# Create operation. Generate form for two entities with 1-to-1 relation

Tags: php, symfony

What I want to achieve:

**User** entity have **UserInfo** property where is stored all info about User. I wan't to create **UserInfo** entity when **User** entity is created and link these two.

UserType:

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('password', 'password') //drugi argument robi input jako password
    ;

    $builder->add('info', new UserInfoType());
}
...
```

User:

```
...

/**
 * @var UserInfo
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserInfo", mappedBy="owner", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * */
private $info;

...
```

UserInfo:

```
 /** 
 * @var User
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="info", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $owner;
...

 /**
 * Set owner
 *
 * @param \Custom\AzureusBundle\Entity\User $owner
 * @return UserInfo
 */
public function setOwner(\Custom\AzureusBundle\Entity\User $owner)
{
    $owner->setInfo($this);
    $this->owner = $owner;

    return $this;
}
```

Why after creating User and UserType at the same time (same form) userInfo hasn't owner_id value in database? These entities are not linking each other after creating.

I assume that I should call setOwner() function somewhere. But I don't know where.

Comment: Probably in your controller.  $user = new User;  $userInfo = new UserInfo.  $userInfo->setOwner($user);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cerad said in comment above I should create UserInfo in User controller (Create function).

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new User();
        $user_info = new UserInfo();
        $entity->setInfo($user_info);
        $user_info->setOwner($entity);
        ...

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            ...
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->persist($user_info);
            ...
```

Comment: You could also adjust user->setInfo to call userInfo->setOwner.  That would probably make more sense and eliminate the extra call.